# How to concatenate pandas DataFrame with built-in logic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas data frame and I would like to produce the output shown in the `expected` data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'],
                    'b':['eee', 'fff', 'ggg', 'hhh']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'],
                    'b':['eee', 'fff', 'ggg', 'hhh'],
                    'update': ['', 'X', '', 'Y']})
expected = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'],
                         'b': ['eee', 'X', 'ggg', 'Y']})
```

I tried to apply some concatenation logic but this is not producing the expected output.

```
df1.set_index('b')
df2.set_index('update')
out = pd.concat([df1[~df1.index.isin(df2.index)], df2])

print(out)
         a    b   update
0  aaa  eee
1  bbb  fff  X
2  ccc  ggg
3  ddd  hhh  Y
```

From this output I can produce the expected output but I was wondering if this logic can be built directly inside the `concat` call?

```
def fx(row):
    if row['update'] is not '':
        row['b'] = row['update']
    return row

result = out.apply(lambda x : fx(x),axis=1)
result.drop('update', axis=1, inplace=True)
print(result)
     a        b
0  aaa      eee
1  bbb      X
2  ccc      ggg
3  ddd      Y
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use builtin `update` by replacing '' with `nan` i.e

```
df1['b'].update(df2['update'].replace('',np.nan))

    a    b
0  aaa  eee
1  bbb    X
2  ccc  ggg
3  ddd    Y
```

You can also use `np.where` i.e

```
out = df1.assign(b=np.where(df2['update'].eq(''), df2['b'], df2['update']))
```

Comment: You can alos using combine_first

Comment: @Wen jezrael did that

Comment: Aha, :-) just saw that

Answer (score 3):

Use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df1['b'] = df2['update'].mask(lambda x: x=='').combine_first(df1['b'])
#alternative
#df1['b'] = df2['update'].mask(lambda x: x=='').fillna(df1['b'])

print (df1)
     a    b
0  aaa  eee
1  bbb    X
2  ccc  ggg
3  ddd    Y
```

But is necessary same index values in both `DataFrame`s.

Comment: After using replace we can extend the solutions to as many as possible

Comment: @Michael How about doing a timing test on your data and finding out?

Comment: I think `out = df1.assign(b=np.where(df2['update'].eq(''), df2['b'], df2['update']))` should be fastest

Answer (score 3):

How about with [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)

```
df1['b'].update(df2.mask(df2=='')['update'])


>>> df1
     a    b
0  aaa  eee
1  bbb    X
2  ccc  ggg
3  ddd    Y
```

Comment: Instead of masking over the complete dataframe better to limit it to series like `df1['b'].update(df2['update'].mask(df2['update']==''))`